# Image normalization

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, computer-vision, mnist

In my perspective, image normalization is to make every pixel to be normalized with an value between 0 and 1, am I right?

But what does the following code mean?

```
image_size = 28      # Pixel width and height.
pixel_depth = 255.0  # Number of levels per pixel.

for image in image_files:
  image_file = os.path.join(folder, image)

  try:
    image_data = (ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float) - 
                pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth  # WHY ??
    if image_data.shape != (image_size, image_size):
      raise Exception('Unexpected image shape: %s' % str(image_data.shape))
    dataset[num_images, :, :] = image_data
    num_images = num_images + 1

  except IOError as e:
    print('Could not read:', image_file, ':', e, '- it\'s ok, skipping.')
```

Comment: Normalization can mean many things. Not necessarily 0 to 1. Hint: why not -0.5 to 0.5?

Comment: Right!! But what's the difference?

Comment: It looks like this code it part of some hyper/multi spectral imaging. For those techniques this is not the way to do normalization. What the code does is simply turn a number of pixcel into a data cube and transform them from 8bit images to a array with 64/32 bit floats between -0.5 and 0.5. futhermore it checks if the resolution is the same.

Comment: @J.Goedhart Yes, you're right. Maybe I asked a bad question. But what's the difference between using a normalized [-0.5, 0.5] dataset and a normalized [0, 1] dataset in machine learning?

Comment: I don't think there is the most important thing is that you give the computer the same numbers. You can also use a range of floats between 0. and 255. . If you want a more general import I would suggest that you look to the bitdepth of the image and depending on that devide the images by 2**bitdepth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)) is merely the process of *changing* the range of pixel intensity values.

The choice of the new range is up to you.

In the case you've shown, it looks like the range -0.5 .. 0.5 has been chosen.

Comment: I got it. But what the difference of using different range as dataset in machine learning?

Comment: That's a completely different question. And it is a topic I'm not familiar with. One thing that I can think of is that is automatically divides the data in positive and negative numbers. Which is handy when you're e.g. trying to find the middle of the range (which is 0 in this case).